# IIS SMTP server (Installed on local server) in parallel to Google Apps

Tags: iis, smtp

I am currently using free version of Google Apps for hosting my email.It works great for **my official mails my email on Google is support@mydomain.com.**

In addition I'm sending out high volume mails (registrations, forgotten passwords, newsletters etc) from the website (www.mydomain.com) using IIS SMTP installed on my windows machine.

**These emails are sent from talk@mydomain.com**

**My problem is that when I send email from the website using IIS SMTP to a mail address
support@mydomain.com I don’t receive the email to Google apps**. (I only receive these emails if I install a pop service on the server with the support@mydomain.com email box).
It seems that the **IIS SMTP is ignoring the domain MX records** and just delivers these emails to my local server.

**Here are my DNS records for domain.com:**

```
mydomain.com  A 82.80.200.20 3600s     
mydomain.com  TXT v=spf1 ip4: 82.80.200.20 a mx ptr include:aspmx.googlemail.com ~all 
mydomain.com  MX preference: 10 exchange: aspmx2.googlemail.com  3600s 
mydomain.com  MX preference: 10 exchange: aspmx3.googlemail.com  3600s 
mydomain.com  MX preference: 10 exchange: aspmx4.googlemail.com  3600s 
mydomain.com  MX preference: 10 exchange: aspmx5.googlemail.com  3600s 
mydomain.com  MX preference: 1 exchange: aspmx.l.google.com  3600s 
mydomain.com  MX preference: 5 exchange: alt1.aspmx.l.google.com  3600s 
mydomain.com  MX preference: 5 exchange: alt2.aspmx.l.google.com  3600s
```

Please help!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:

Problem Solved.

I had a **pop3 service** installed on the server from the time i wasn't using google apps.
this created a local domain under the smtp called mydomain.com.
removing the pop3 email box's along with the **local domain smtp solved my problem**.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is ignoring the MX record. In the SMTP service you've told it that it's domain is mydomain.com, therefore it believes that it should receive all mail for that domain and hence sends it to itself.

Depending on the version of windows server/IIS you're using, reconfiguring this is different. However, the basic gist is that you tell the SMTP service it is not authoritative for that domain.

This question is really much more appropriate for Server Fault than Stack Overflow, you'd probably get a better response there.

Comment: thanks. My windows is 2003 server and the smtp is virtual smtp that comes with iis. My smtp name is the same as  the machine name (called ml_server) , i also changed the Fully-qualified domain name of the smtp to mail.mydomain.com , but it still doesn't work.